# Help in wiping off Ubuntu 12.04!

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, ati, graphics

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and my laptop is running on high temparatures(70-80 C). I tried to figure out the graphics card issues (I have intel and AMD radeon), i activated both and none of the are working(The details icon doesn't show any thing under graphics). I made a USB HD bootable with windows 8 in it and boot order and bios settings everything are normal and correct but laptop is not booting from the USB, it directly goes to ubuntu. Can any one please point where the things are going wrong and any idea on how to solve them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into `GRUB` issue and `/dev/sda` as this is kinda of famous for this kind of trivia that you are encountering now.